# Jquery galleryView loading issues: loader image not displaying, taking awhile

Tags: jquery, galleryview

I've got an online portfolio that I'm putting up:

[Image Gallery](http://www.fifephotography.com/index.php/admin/portfolio/bridals)

I've got a php script that selects at most 15 images from a database that contains the urls for the images. e.g.

> foreach ($database->result as $img) { echo `'<a href="path/to/image/' . $img . '">'`; ?>

When the page first loads, the scroll bar expands as if it is loading invisible images (indeed I think that's what it is doing). Then the javascript kicks in and the gallery loads. I have two questions: first, the image loader is not displaying at all. I don't mind if it takes a bit, as long as the user knows the images are loading. Any ideas why it's not showing up?

Second, is there a way to speed up the process? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok....I figured it out. I found [this page](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/37/47/) which tells you basically how to do that...works like a charm!

As for the cutting down on loading time, I found a site that said you should crop the thumbnails yourself, rather than resizing through javascript. I don't remember where I found that, but all seems to be working!